# Redux store can not get state from reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I created the store but find that there is no state in the store, but the reducer send to store have state.
As there is no state in store, I can not init my component at all...

Here is the error message from simulator:

[image: error message]

Here is the code:

configureStore:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist';
import reducers from '../reducers';

var isDebuggingInChrome = __DEV__ && !!window.navigator.userAgent;
var logger = createLogger({
predicate: (getState, action) => isDebuggingInChrome,
    collapsed: true,
    duration: true,
});

var middlewares = compose(applyMiddleware(thunk, logger), autoRehydrate());

export default function configureStore() {
    console.log('Reducer'+reducers)

    const store = createStore(reducers, undefined, middlewares);

    persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage});

  if (isDebuggingInChrome) {
      window.store = store;
  }
     return store;
}
```

reducers/prepareConnect:

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const initialState = {
    readyButtonState:false, 
    appearImage:'./img/bpm1_setwifi_unready@2x.png'
}

export default function prepareConnect(state = initialState,action) {
    switch (action.type){
        case types.CONNECT_CLICK_READY: {
            return Object.assign({},state,{
                readyButtonState:action.currentState,
                appearImage:action.currentImage,
            })
        }
            break;
        default:
            return state;
            break;
    }
}
```

reducers/index

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import prepareConnect from './prepareConnect';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    prepareConnect
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Here is the container/prepareConnectView

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {
    StyleSheet,
    View
} from 'react-native';

import Actions from '../actions';

import Upper from "../components/prepareConnect-view/Upper";
import Bottom from "../components/prepareConnect-view/Bottom";

class PrepareConnectView extends Component {
    static props = {}

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Upper/>
            <Bottom {...this.props}/>
        </View>
    )
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        buttonState: state.readyButtonState,
        appearImage: state.appearImage,
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(PrepareConnectView);
```

Here is component/prepareConnect/Bottom

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View,
    Text,
    Button,
} from 'react-native';

import screenRelated from '../../Macro&Const/UIConst'
import BasicStyle from '../../styles/Basic'

class Bottom extends Component {
static props = {
    isClick:false,
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            isClick:false,
    }
}

_onPressButton = () =>{
    //TODO:点击的时候去创建Action, 并且Dispatch
    //FIXME: 为什么这里去传递的参数给不到actionCreator里面
    //发现压根在用的时候就是undefined, 为什么拿不到, 明明已经写了是False了.
    this.props.isClick = !this.props.isClick;
    this.setState({
        isClick:!this.state.isClick,
    })
    this.props.actions.connectReadyClick( this.state.isClick)
}

_nextButtonClick = () =>{
    //TODO: 只要能点击 就是跳进下一个界面
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={BasicStyle.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}
                              style={styles.upperButton}>
                <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                    <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                    source={require(this.props.appearImage)}/>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Ready to connect</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.nextButton}>
                <Button onPress={this._nextButtonClick}
                        disabled={!this.props.buttonState}
                        title='Next'
                        color='red'
                        style={styles.nextButton}/>
            </View>
        </View>
    )}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    innerContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    image:{
        left:10,
        height:20,
        width:140,
    },
    text:{
        position:'relative',
        color: '#AEAEAE',
        left:22,
    },
upperButton:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'center',
},
    nextButton:{
        position:'absolute',
        top:230,
        width:screenRelated.screenWidth+10,
        alignItems:'center',
        borderColor: 'blue',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 4,
    }
})

export default Bottom;
```

Comment: How did you check, that there is no state in your store?

Comment: @trixn First, the simulator give me an error, tell me that something I want to use is undefined.Then, I check every step from Chorme and find that the state of store in undefined, empty.

Comment: What is the complete error message? Please add this to your question.

Comment: @trixn Although I think it is not related of this issue, but I add that.
The point I think is that store not get the state from reducer.
I want know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a code snippet. Persisting does not work because localStorage is not available in the stack snippets but that shouldn't wipe your store anyways. So as you can see, there is an inital state loaded into your store. Open your console, to see the output.

Try to fix your error first and see if that helped. Did you restart your packaging tool? And do you use `require()` anywhere in the rest of your code?

```js
const {combineReducers, applyMiddleware, createStore, compose} = Redux;
const thunk = ReduxThunk.default;
const {persistStore, autoRehydrate} = ReduxPersist;

const initialState = {
    readyButtonState:false, 
    appearImage:'./img/bpm1_setwifi_unready@2x.png'
}

const prepareConnect = (state = initialState, action)  => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'a type': {
      return Object.assign({},state, {
                  readyButtonState: action.currentState,
                  appearImage: action.currentImage,
      })
      break;
    }
    default:
      return state;
      break;
 }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    prepareConnect
});

var logger = reduxLogger.createLogger({
  predicate: (getState, action) => true,
  collapsed: true,
  duration: true,
});

var middlewares = compose(applyMiddleware(thunk, logger), autoRehydrate());

const store = createStore(rootReducer, undefined, middlewares);

persistStore(store);

const state = store.getState();

console.log("STATE:", state);
```

```html
<p id="store"></p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.7.1/redux.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/redux-logger@3.0.6/dist/redux-logger.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux-thunk/2.2.0/redux-thunk.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux-persist/4.8.2/redux-persist.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

I've created a fiddle too, because localStorage works there:
https://jsfiddle.net/ow4z71ac/

As you can see in the console, your store is initalized as expected. It looks like this:

```
{
    "prepareConnect": {
        "readyButtonState": false,
        "appearImage": "./img/bpm1_setwifi_unready@2x.png"
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

The way you map state to props will not work. Take a look at your rootReducer. The name of every reducer you pass to `combineReducer` will be taken as a key in the top level of your store.

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    prepareConnect
});
```

That's why your store looks like this:

```
{
    "prepareConnect": {
        "readyButtonState": false,
        "appearImage": "./img/bpm1_setwifi_unready@2x.png"
    }
}
```

And that's how you try to map your state to props:

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        // readyButtonState does not exist in state but in state. prepareConnect.readyButtonState
        buttonState: state.readyButtonState,
        appearImage: state.appearImage,
    };
}
```

That is also why your `require()` call fails because `this.props.appearImage` is `undefined`.

You can change, how the portion of state that the reducer creates looks like by renaming the reducer when importing it or by defining your own keys:

```js
import initial from './prepareConnect';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    initial
});
```

or

```js
import prepareConnect from './prepareConnect';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    initial: prepareConnect
});
```

Then you can access your inital data in `state.initial`.

Comment: THX,I will check it latter.

Comment: It seems that our code is exactly same.
BUT, I am still can not get the state.
The packaing tool U mean is npm and yarn? I did not change them at all,nor restart.
And the require function, I use that in my component to give the image source.

Comment: The error says that you are trying to require something undefined. Maybe the path you are passing is incorrect? Could you add the code from `Bottom.js` and how you connect your component to the store? And could you describe how exactly you check that the store is empty in chrome?

Comment: I get it, How fool I am.
Actually, I get the state, but I use `console.log(store.getState())`directally, And the Chorme give me the result is [object Object], I suppose, it is means that there is no state.
THS for ur patience for a fresh man, I guess I can figure out the simulator error by myself.

Comment: Okay nice to hear but you can see my updated answer for an explanation what you have to change in order to make it work.

Comment: Wow, cool ,man. Big THX for ur generous for a fresh man. I get the core point of why I get this error, that I do not get the data structure clearly.I give me a great lesson, and it is the first time I get the valued answer of my own question, Have a great day.